# Why the query is not working?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have made the schema on the sqlfiddle.

I am beginner to database.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21535

I want to get all employees in the cleaning department

```
select * from emp,department 
  where dname = 'cleaning' 
        and dno = dnum;

select * from emp e,department d
  where d.dname = 'cleaning' 
        and e.dno = d.dnum; 

select * from emp as e,department as d
  where d.dname = 'cleaning' 
        and e.dno = d.dnum;
```

But the third query is not working . why?

I am reading from the book Fundamentals_of_Database_Systems.(Elmasri)

There are many queries which has used `as`.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from emp  e,department  d
  where d.dname = 'cleaning' 
        and e.dno = d.dnum;
```

works fine

Just get rif of `as`. It is used with columns

UPDATE with join

```
select * from emp  e JOIN department  d ON e.dno = d.dnum
  where d.dname = 'cleaning';
```

Comment: It would also be better to use an explicit `JOIN` operator rather than the outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause - especially for a beginner

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name agree that explicit JOIN is better to read

Comment: @StanislavL How i can use join here?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't support using statement `AS` to determine alias for tables. In SQL standart it can be used only for change name of columns in query result. However, most of DB systems support `as` also like creating aliase for table in query.